# Adding sortBy attribute programatically to primefaces DataTable Column

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I'm trying to put the `sortBy` attribute into the primefaces datatable `Column` programatically. I have inherited from DataTable, and creating my own Columns using a custom `getColumns()` call.

Unfortunately there seems to be no clean way to insert the sortBy attribute to the column, since the method yet doesn't know the context it is in.

```
public List<Column> getColumns() {
    if (columns == null) {
        columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
        String[] columnStrings = getShowColumns().split(",");
        for (String columnString : columnStrings) {
            Column column = getColumnByType(columnString.trim());
            if (column != null) {
                //here I have to add the sortBy Expression somehow,
                //but there is no context to construct it from
                //column.setSortBy(ValueExpression)
                columns.add(column);
            }
        }
    }
    return columns;
}
```

It seems obvious to me, that I am missing something, but I am lost rightnow. The `Column` seems to be filled with that `ValueExpression` somewhere else, but I can't find out where...

I tried to go through all the code using the debugger, but I can't figure out when the ValueExpression is generated in the original implementation. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ValueExpression` for `sortBy` is not stored anywhere if the column doesn't have `sortBy` specified, which is your case. You have to create your own `ValueExpression` for each column which should be sortable.

I assume you know the column type and value so you can try this:

```
Column column = getColumnByType(columnString.trim());
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
ExpressionFactory elFactory = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
ValueExpression valueExpresion = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, column.getValue(), column.getType());
```

Else if you don't know the type and value :

```
 String valueExprs = "#{data.street}"; // for example
    ...
    Column column = getColumnByType(columnString.trim());
    ...
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression valueExpression = elFactory.createValueExpression( elContext, valueExprs, String.class);
```

And now you can set sortBy :

```
column.setValueExpression("sortBy", valueExpression);
```

Notice using `column.setValueExpression` instead of `column.setSortBy` - it causes less troubles and work most of the time.

Hope it helped !

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know I could just pull in the singleton context to make it work. I still don't get when and why the context is passed by reference then, but that is a whole other question. thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. You can pull the context in any jsf related "object" like beans,phaseListeners, etc. But yea, you will have to ask in separated question to get detailed answer from more experienced users and pros like BalusC.